# Angular Cannot read property 'GetCarList' of undefined Error

Tags: angular

I want to order my car list in a child component by select control from another child component. But when i try to change i get error like 'Cannot read property 'GetCarList' of undefined'. I'm not too much experienced on Angular so i couldn't find a way in the internet.

And here's my codes;

- Parent Component

*index.html;*

```
<rac-carlistinfo></rac-carlistinfo>
<rac-carlistitems></rac-carlistitems>
```

- Child Component with Select Control

*info.html;*

```
<select id="slcOrder" name="slcOrder" class="m-select" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of orderList" value="{{ item?.Code }}">{{ item?.ShortDescription }}</option>
</select>
```

*info.ts (CarsListInfoComponent)*

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { SiteService } from '../../../../services/site';
import { CarsListItemsComponent } from './items';

@Component({
    selector: 'rac-carlistinfo',
    templateUrl: './info.html'
})

export class CarsListInfoComponent {
    errorMsg: string;

    orderList: any;

    @Output() carListOrder: CarsListItemsComponent;

    constructor(private service: SiteService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.GetLangContent();
    }

    onChange(event) {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;

        this.carListOrder.GetCarList(target.value);
    }

    GetLangContent() {
        this.service.get("Site", "GetLangContentByCode", "order").subscribe((resData: any) => {
            this.orderList = resData;
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
    }
}
```

- Child Component with Car List

*items.html;*

```
<div *ngFor="let item of carList">
    <h2>{{ item?.Title }}</h2>
    <span>{{ item?.Price }} TL</span>
</div>
```

*items.ts (CarsListItemsComponent)*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SiteService } from '../../../../services/site';

@Component({
    selector: 'rac-carlistitems',
    templateUrl: './items.html'
})

export class CarsListItemsComponent {
    errorMsg: string;

    carList: any;

    constructor(private service: SiteService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.GetCarList();
    }

    public GetCarList(order: string = null) {
        this.service.get("Site", "GetCarList", order).subscribe((resData: any) => {
            this.carList = resData;
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind posting the whole info.ts or if it has too many lines, just post the constructor

Comment: it has too many lines. i just added related codes.

Comment: okay. is your GetCarList a public method?

Comment: it wasn't but i changed it to public and it didn't make any sense. i changed my codes and wrote all ts codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here:

1. `@Output() carListOrder: CarsListItemsComponent;` this doesn't make sense. `Output()` is meant to emit events.
2. `@Output() carListOrder: CarsListItemsComponent;` you are defining this as of `CarsListItemsComponent` but you actually have not any reference to that component. That's why you get

> Cannot read property 'GetCarList' of undefined Error

In order to get this working you have to:

1. Add `Input` (e.g. carList) to your `rac-carlistitems` component.
2. Add `Output` (e.g. infoChange) to your `rac-carlistinfo` component.
3. Then listen for `infoChange` to the container component which includes the other ones and move that `GetCarList` there.

Putting all these down.

```js
//CarsListInfoComponent

@Output() infoChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

onChange(event) {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;

        this.infoChange.emit(target.value);
    }
```

```js
//CarsListItemsComponent
@Input() carList: any[];
```

```html
//Container component html

<rac-carlistinfo (infoChange)="GetCarList($event)"></rac-carlistinfo>
<rac-carlistitems [carList]="carList"></rac-carlistitems>
```

```js
//Container component ts

carList: any[] = [];

GetCarList(order: string = null) {
        this.service.get("Site", "GetCarList", order).subscribe((resData: any) => {
            this.carList = resData;
        }, resError => this.errorMsg = resError);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer man. It worked well and now i learned the component communication in Angular better with your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's another problem my friend. It works great but the car list uses owlcarousel. When i changed the order owlcarousel didn't work even if i call it again after data changed as well as i tried it in ngOnChanges event.

Comment: You should better ask an other question for this issue.

Comment: i will try some different ways then maybe i can ask another question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not familiar on using `@Output`.

If I were you this will be my approach.

```
export class CarsListInfoComponent {
errorMsg: string;

orderList: any;

constructor(private service: SiteService, private carListOrder: CarsListItemsComponent) {
}

  ...

onChange(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;

    this.carListOrder.GetCarList(target.value);
}
```

Comment: it didn't get any error but car list order didn't change as well. do you have any idea?